# For what p $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(ln(n))^p}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

so the question is for what p this series converges ?

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(ln(n))^p}$

I really don't know where to start , I tried the integral test and comparing with $\frac{1}{n^p}$ but no result .

any ideas ?

Comment: Try to prove that for all $p$ and for all sufficiently large $n$, $(\log n)^p\lt n$.

Comment: Alternatively, do you know the Cauchy Condensation test?

Comment: you mean that one with the root ? if so, yes

Comment: Cauchy Condensation test $\ne$ root test.

Comment: No, I mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Comment: No @WasFr , no root in CCT. The most common form of it uses the prime $\;2\;$ , though other primes help as well.

Comment: yes yes nice one, so I used it and just need to show that :
$\frac{2^n}{n^p}$ converges to $\infty$ from some N.
any idea ?

Comment: Now you can use the ratio test (D'Alembert's), @WasFr: $$\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^p}\frac{n^p}{2^n}=2\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^p\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2\cdot 1=2>1$$

Comment: yes, absolutely thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For none. For any fixed $p$, $(\ln n)^p<n$ for $n$ large enough and
$${1\over n}<{1\over (\ln n)^p}.$$

Comment: Oh ok, and how can I prove this inequality ?

Comment: Calculate the limit of quotient $(\log n)/n^{1/p}$.

Comment: oh yes I used LaHospital and found that it should be equal to $\infty$ . and it worked.
is there another easier way or that is the easiest ?

Comment: I think that this is the easiest.

Comment: ok thank you for your help