# proving that a series is divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Let $a_j=\bigg(\ln (j+e)\bigg)^{jp}$, where $j\in \mathbb{N}$ and $p>0$ is a real number. I want to show that the series
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{a_j}{a_{j+1}}$$ is convergent for $p>1$ and divergent for $ 0<p\leq 1$. I did the former case by comparing it with a $p-$ series. I have a difficulty in the latter case. Please give me some hint.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\frac{a_j}{a_{j+1}}=\sum\frac{\left(\ln (j+e)\right)^{jp}}{\left(\ln (j+1+e)\right)^{(j+1)p}}=\sum\left(\frac{\ln (j+e)}{\ln (j+1+e)}\right)^{jp}\frac{1}{\left(\ln (j+1+e)\right)^p}\cdot $$ Applying limit comparison test with the divergent series $\sum \frac{1}{\left(\ln (j+1+e)\right)^p}$ we get 
$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{\ln (j+e)}{\ln (j+1+e)}\right)^{jp}\frac{1}{\left(\ln (j+1+e)\right)^p}}{\frac{1}{\left(\ln (j+1+e)\right)^p}}=\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln (j+e)}{\ln (j+1+e)}\right)^{jp}=1,$$ and conclude $\sum\frac{a_j}{a_{j+1}}$ is divergent for all $p>0$.

Comment: Thank you. I think the divergent series you used as a comparison  diverges only for $0<p\leq 1$ and that is what I want.

Comment: You are welcome. you can look "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672200/for-what-p-sum-n-2-infty-frac1lnnp-converges" for that series.